# Limiting action via session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

So I have implemented a session system, but I have some troubles.
First of all, when I create a new pokemon, I link the session[:user_id] to it with this code.

```
@pokemon = Pokemon.new(params[:pokemon])
@pokemon.user_id = @current_user
```

When I create one with my account 1, the user_id is 1, but when I create a pokemon with my account 2, the user_id is set to 1 again.

Also, how can I protect the edit/show/destroy pages to sessions only ? Right now, I can edit any of the pokemons with any of the account, if I use directly the address bar.

I put my controllers in [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/schatteleyn/d7be7c83628ad5fd71f6) (I suppose it all happens in them)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not an answer, but is too long to be a comment.

First, I am not sure `@pokemon.user_id` can be set to an user instance, I would try with:

```
@pokemon.user = current_user
```

or:

```
@pokemon.user_id = current_user.id
```

Second, I would not user `@current_user`, instead `current_user` as above.

Third, it is not clear where you are setting `session[:user_id]`, to debug your problem I would print all related variables in create action of pokemons controller:

```
  def create
    @pokemon = Pokemon.new(params[:pokemon])
    @pokemon.user_id = current_user 
    p current_user
    p session[:user_id]
```

## Secure actions

You can scope your resource with `current_user`:

```
@pokemon = current_user.pokemons.find(params[:id])
```

That way you will find just pokemons for that user. I am not sure if this method raises an exception or just returns `nil` when user has not created pokemon with `params[:id]`. You have to handle whichever of these two (exception or nil) to redirect other users to another page:

### for exception

```
begin
@pokemon = current_user.pokemons.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  redirect_to :back
end
```

### for nil

```
@pokemon = current_user.pokemons.find(params[:id])
unless @pokemon
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: The two puts send me the object user, the second send the id. Both are the correct one (number 2). But I indeed had to use current_user.id ! Do you have any help for the second part ?